# Artikel mit unzählbarem Wort: »die ganze Zeit«

Tags: article

*Zeit* ist ein unzählbares Wort (wie auch *Wasser, Glück* usw.) Darum braucht man keinen Artikel in Sätzen wie:

> Ich habe heute Zeit für dich.

Aber warum ist der Artikel im nächsten Satz optional und im dritten Satz zwingend erforderlich?

> Ich habe **[eine]** kurze Zeit bei meiner Tante gewohnt.
>
> Ich habe **die** ganze Zeit gelacht.

Comment: Ich zweifle an, dass der Artikel im vorletzten Satz nur optional ist. Artikellos denkbar wäre der Satz mMn. nur stark umgangssprachlich.

Comment: Auch Wasser und Glück können mit Artikel verwendet werden. "Das Glück ist mir hold."

Comment: Gute Frage. Ich wollte auch zuerst einwenden, dass da kein Unterschied zwischen *Zeit* und deinen anderen Beispielen besteht, dann fiel mir auf, dass du das auch gar nicht behauptet hast.

Comment: Zeit ist aber messbar und personifizierbar (_Die Zeit heilt alle Wunden/r_), u.U. ist sie sogar halbwegs zählbar (_zu vielen Zeiten war Krieg normal_).

Comment: @npst: Vielleicht spielt ein regionaler Unterschied eine Rolle. DWDS bringt Tausende von Treffern für kurze Zeit ohne Artikel, z. B. *Er lebte kurze Zeit in Köln , dann in Bonn , seit dem Mai 1879 in Düsseldorf und ließ sich 1884 dauernd in Köln nieder, seine Muße schriftstellerischer Tätigkeit widmend*. Das klingt mir gar nicht nach Umgangssprache, schon gar nicht nach **starker**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Zeit* hat unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.

Die physikalische Größe Zeit `t`, die allgegenwärtig fließt ist nicht zählbar, und es gibt nicht *eine Zeit*, *zwei Zeiten*, *mehr Zeiten*. Das hat aber damit nichts zu tun, dass man nicht *die Zeit* sagen kann - wir meinen ja die eine, bestimmte, allgegenwärtig fließende Zeit. Es gibt nicht *eine Milch* oder *zwei Milche*, aber der Satz

> Hol bitte die Milch, die auf dem Tisch steht.

ist dennoch vollkommen korrekt, weil wir nun mal die bestimmte Milch möchten. Daher sind auch diese Sätze korrekt:

> Die Zeit heilt alle Wunden.
>
> Wenn die Zeit bloß nicht so schnell verginge!

Das Wort *Zeit* kann aber auch *Zeitabschnitt* bedeuten. Wird das Wort in dieser Bedeutung benutzt, ist es auf alle Fälle quantifizierbar.

> Das war eine schöne Zeit. = Das war ein schöner Zeitabschnitt.
>
> Auf uns kommen schlechte Zeiten zu. = Auf uns kommen schlechte Tage / Jahre / Jahrzehnte (=Zeiteinheiten, Zeitabschnitte) zu.
>
> Ich habe die *ganze* Zeit gelacht! = Ich habe über den gesamten besagten Zeitabschnitt gelacht.

Das interessante im letzten Satz ist nicht der Artiel *die*, sondern das Wort *ganze*.

Um das Milch-Beispiel nochmal aufzugreifen:

> Wenn du schon einkaufen bist, besorg mir bitte eine Milch (=eine Milchpackung).
>
> Er hat die ganze Milch getrunken (=nicht alle Milch auf der Welt, sondern das ganze Glas).

Comment: Danke, @Barth. Gute Erklärung.

Comment: @user22750 Es würde mich dann freuen, wenn du die Antwort über den grünen Haken akzeptieren würdest.

Comment: gerne. War meine erste Frage, und das mit den Haken wusste ich noch nicht.